# What Stack Exchange site is best for asking a question about the Chrome browser?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

The question relates to how to close all tabs and windows of a specific profile.

So, what's the best SE site to ask such a question?

Comment: [su] is your best bet. Do read their help center docs before posting though (and make sure to search the site for this as well - might already have been asked and answered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) seems like a good fit but please [search](https://superuser.com/search?q=) their site before asking your question as it may already have an answer there.